# one JSON call returned with many?

Tags: php, jquery, json

My question is... How to make json have 1 call back with several objects.

I will use this example of 3 values to be returned... Here is the calclickM.php file, but I can not understand why it is not woking...

```
    <?php  
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  

$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE date = '".$choice."' group by date"; $res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
$dayPowerP = array ('dayPowerP');
?>

<?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("m",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("m"); $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE month(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
$monthPowerP = array ('monthPowerP');
?>

<?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y"); $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  

$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE year(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
$yearPowerP = array ('yearPowerP');
?>
<?php
$outarr['dayPowerP'] = $dayPowerP;
$outarr['monthPowerP'] = $monthPowerP;
$outarr['yearPowerP'] = $yearPowerP;
echo json_encode($outarr);
?>
```

Here is the Jquery I am using to post and the json

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#datepicker').datepicker({maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));           
            $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",   
            url: "calclickM.php",                  
            data: {choice: dateText}, 
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(json_data) {  
            $('#apDiv2').html(json_data['dayPowerP']);  
            $('#apDiv6').html(json_data['monthPowerP']);  
            $('#apDiv8').html(json_data['yearPowerP']);  
           } 
        })           
    }});
});
```

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: 7 questions, 0 accepted answers. You're hindering your chances of getting more answers.

Comment: Hi, the last time I used the "answer box", I was told not to. I thank all that add comments and examples in the "add comment"

Answer (score 2):

At first the `load` method you are calling is making an AJAX GET request to your server. You probably support both POST and GET requests in your PHP script.

Secondly you have some errors in the your `$.ajax` calls. There are some unterminated strings, the data variable you are using as `('#apDiv9').html(data)` isn't defined and if it was, it will be probably contain JSON data that you can't directly put in an HTML element.

Last, but not least, the second attempt won't make your code faster. A browser can only support a limited number of parallel ajax requests (1-2). You are still making the same number of requests and some of them need to wait for the others to complete. Re-design your code so that you return everything in a single call.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do everyining in a single call. This is where I am confused...

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to your immediate problem, but your code needs some serious refactoring. The level of repetition here hurts my eyes. The second code block, the one with the ajax-calls, could be changed to something like this:

```
var pages = [
  { url: "dayPower.php",   div: "#apDiv4"  },
  { url: "dayGraph",       div: "#apDiv2"  },
  { url: "monthPower.php", div: "#apDiv6"  },
  { url: "monthGraph",     div: "#apDiv9"  },
  { url: "yearPower.php",  div: "#apDiv8"  },
  { url: "yearPower",      div: "#apDiv10" }
};

for ( var i=0; i<pages.length; i++ ) {
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",  
    url: pages[i].url,                 
    data: { choice: dateText}, 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(json_data ) 
      (pages[i].div).html(data).show(); // Did you mean json_data here?
    }
  });
}
```

The case is similar with the first piece of code in your question.

Once again, I know it won't solve the actual problem, but it will make it easier to implement the solution when you (or someone else) finds it.

**EDIT**

On second thought, I can see at least one strange thing: in the success-function you call the parameter `json_data`, but you access a variable that you've called `data`. Did you intend to name them the same thing?

Comment: the success function needs to be changed to 
"success: function( json_data ) {
      ('#apDiv10').html(json_data).show();
    }"

Comment: As Kgiannakakis wrote above, I need to return everything in a single call, but I do not get that... Thus my confusion.

Comment: Returning everything in a single call requires you to change the code on the server side. You can worry about the client later :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do what you are asking, but you will need to handle the results yourself.  Essentially all your Ajax calls have the same parameters, but different resultsets.  So first, the client side code that does the magic:

```
$.post('datePacked.php', {choice: dateText}, function(data) {
    $('#apDiv2').html(data['dayPower']);
    $('#apDiv4').html(data['dayGraph']);
    $('#apDiv6').html(data['monthPower']);
    $('#apDiv9').html(data['monthGraph']);
    $('#apDiv8').html(data['yearPower']);
    $('#apDiv10').html(data['yearGraph']);
});
```

If you refactored your HTML so taht you actually match the div Ids with the result of your JSon response, you can simplify the call even further:

```
$.post('datePacked.php', {choice: dateText}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(id, value) {
        $('#'+id).html(value);
    });
});
```

On the server side your new `datePacked.php` needs to return a JSON result that provides a hash of names to content.  Essentially it will look something like this:

```
{ "dayPower" : "<p>My Content</p>", "dayGraph" : "<p>Day graph</p>", ... }
```

The ellipsis is there for you to fill in the remainder of the content.  Choosing meaningful id names for your HTML elements is not only good practice, it can save you a lot of repitition if you take advantage of it.  An example of that would be the second form of the client example.  This is a case where the content has to be JSON for it to work--unless you want to split up a DOM returned by the server.

Comment: Hello, I thought I needed to write jason_data in this, but I think I am not understanding right because now there seems to be a lack of this but yet it is a json ???

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand.  Are you asking if the response from the `datePacked.php` should be JSON?  The answer is yes.  The content can also be JSON, or it can be HTML embedded in the JSON.  The important thing is that you are extracting the content based on the key name in the hash you get from the server.

Comment: My meaning is that I should need to have "json_encode" or some var that states this json, and from other readings I should have to have $getJSON...  the more I read the less I am understanding... one thing I am happy about, is that the highcharts graph does have a "render to" function that directs what div the graph should go to... that helps me a little... maybe I am thinking to much that it is not clear in my understanding.

Comment: You do need 'json_encode'. It would be something like this: `$d = array('dayPower' => '<p>My Content</p>', 'dayGraph' => '<p>Day graph</p>', ...);` and then serialized with `echo json_encode($d)`. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Another note: JQuery looks for the Content-Type of "application/json", so make sure you set that response header.  Also see this article about JSON in general (example in PHP as well): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I guess I am going to spend my time reading now, as I really cant wrap my head around this... Thanks again for your input !

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what you’re asking, but here’s a couple of points:

1. `$('#apDiv2').load('dayPower.php', {choice: dateText}` does the same thing as `$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "dayPower.php", data: { choice: dateText}`. Both `$.ajax` and `$.load` make HTTP requests via JavaScript, which is what “AJAX” means.
2. Your second block of example code has some basic syntax errors. Here’s the first $.ajax call corrected:

   ```
   $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",  
       url: "dayPower.php",                 
       data: { choice: dateText}, 
       dataType: "json", 
       success: function(json_data ) { // “{” added to start the function block
           ('#apDiv2').html(data).show(); 
       }
   }) // “})” added to end the object literal and function call
   ```

Comment: From what I am told, I need to make a single call, this is where I do not understand.

Comment: In that case, you need a single PHP page that returns all the results. An AJAX “call” is an HTTP request sent to a URL. You need to rewrite your PHP so that one URL returns all the results you’re currently getting from dayPower.php, dayGraph.php and the others.

Answer (score 0):

if you never need call any of this separately, why not just make one ajax call to a php file, package all your data into a multidimensional array, convert to json, and send back to the client.

Once you have this json, you can then break it up with js and figure out what goes where on your front end.

Depending on how much data you're getting it may take a while. If it's a huge query, then breaking it up into several little calls be actually be better. Its asynchronous so at least parts of your page will be loading. while other parts are gathering data.

Comment: The single click of a day on an inline datepicker, will call for 3 HighCharts graphs (24 hours of values for the day, 31 days of the selected month, and the 12 months of the selected year) and then 3 of the sum values of the day, month, year.... so it is not a lot of data. The highcharts graphs would be the thing that would take a few micro seconds as it is a png that will go to the div. Keep in mind, that the highcharts has a function the tells what div the graph will go to in the php file.